# innerHtml on responding ajax method

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using ajax for sending data to `PHP` script and set a query in my database. my codes :

***HTML script*** :

```
<span id="btn_span_<?php echo $user_id ?>">
      <?php if ($online == 1) { ?>
      <button onclick="update_online(1,<?php echo $user_id; ?>,'btn_span_<?php echo $user_id ?>')" class="btn-custom-delete btn btn-status">is active</button>
      <?php } elseif ($online == 0) { ?>
      <button onclick="update_online(0,<?php echo $user_id; ?>,'btn_span_<?php echo $user_id ?>')" class="btn-custom-services btn btn-status">active
      </button>
      <?php } ?>
 </span>
```

***JAVASCRIPT script*** :

```
function update_online(status, id, span_id) {
var settings = {
     "async": true,
     "crossDomain": true,
     "url": "script_edit_status.php?status=" + status + '&id=' + id + '&span_id=' + span_id,
     "method": "GET"
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      var obj = JSON.parse(response);
      var btn = document.getElementById(span_id);
      if (obj.status == "1") {
            btn.innerHTML = "<button onclick='update_online(1,obj.id,obj.span_id)' class='btn-custom-services btn btn-status'>active</button>";
      } else if (obj.status == "0") {
                btn.innerHTML = "<button onclick='update_online(0,obj.id,obj.span_id)' class='btn-custom-delete btn btn-status'>is active</button>";
      }
});
}
```

***PHP script*** :

```
<?php
include_once "../db/connection.php";
$id = $_GET['id'];
$status = $_GET['status'];
$span_id = $_GET['span_id'];
try {
    if ($status == 1) {
        $sql_edit_status = "update api_user set online=0 where id='$id';";
    } elseif ($status == 0) {
        $sql_edit_status = "update api_user set online=1 where id='$id';";
    }
    $conn->query($sql_edit_status);


    $status_arr = array(
        "id" => $id,
        "status" => $status,
        "span_id" => $span_id
    );

    echo json_encode($status_arr);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
```

it is ok for the first action but when I want to click to button for `second time` consol shows following error :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: obj is not defined

The error is for innerHTML that don't send correctly methods...
Can you help me?

Comment: You want to click to button for second time... where is the click event?? and normally the first time it executes because php runs first (before js) and it echo the results but from your code i cant see a click event to recall the php to be executed so basically you are missing a recall to the first part: <span id="btn_span_ where the php is giving you the values.

Comment: @Sigma I think it is about `update_online(1,obj.id,obj.span_id)`.when innerHTML replace new button, `obj` elements doesnt change to json callbacks from previous click

Comment: Try to use <?php echo $user_id; ?> on the update_online function params from the inner to get the fresh values.

Comment: @Sigma please check answer on bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
btn.innerHTML = "<button onclick='update_online(0," + obj.id + "," + obj.span_id + ")' class='btn-custom-delete btn btn-status'>is active</button>";
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. it works good but a problem. it replaces `onclick="update_online(0,4,btn_span_4)"`. how can I replace with `onclick="update_online(0,4,'btn_span_4')"`.(set '' for btn_span_4)

Comment: Something like this:
    `btn.innerHTML = '<button onclick="update_online(0,' + obj.id + ',\'' + obj.span_id + '\')' class="btn-custom-delete btn btn-status">is active</button>';`